# Reusing an expression in SSRS field

Tags: reporting-services

I'm writing a report in SSRS.  I have a report with some fairly long expressions although the calcuations are simple additions, subtractions and mults and divs.  Is there a way to capture the results of an expression for use in a calculation in another field without having to repeat the whole original calculation?  I already do part of the calculation in underlying views.  Is it possible to do something similar to referencing a 'Field.xxx.Value'?  I'm using 2008 R2 for now but will be moving to Sql Server 2012 soon.

Comment: Wow sql server 2012, we are still running 2005...

Answer (score 2):

Supposedly the result of the complex expression that you want to reuse is located in a Text Box named "amt3". Then you can use this to, say, Color it:

```
=iif(ReportItems("amt3").Value  < 0, "Red", "Green")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to repeat a calculation or use a calculated value?

If you want to repeat a calculation you can use inbedded code. Just write some VB that takes in whatever parameters you want and have it output the results.